# Matplotlib ticks at y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem concerning ticks and labels on my graph, that seems to be a really basic question, but i simply cannot figure it out:

I need to start the y-axis of my graph at 1 instead of 0. That is, what i achive with

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([1, 250]) #y-axis limits
```

My problem now is to set the right ticks and their labels.

So i want to start my graph with 1 at the very bottom, followed by 50, 100, 150, 200, 250.

I have played around a lot with yticks, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticks=[1, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]
labels=[1, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]

plt.yticks(ticks, [labels])
```

but i cannot figure out, what iam doing wrong.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Since `labels` already is a list, it should not be enclosed in another list. `plt.yticks(ticks, labels)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I voted to close this question as your suggestion solves the issue straightforwardly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course i tried that before @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.

Thanks to your input, i figured out, that not the "yticks" line was the problem, but the

```
plt.yscale("linear")
```

in the end of my code. Removing this line, it works as expected.

Thank you!